# Excel VBA , object defined error on last row

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

can any one find any error? For some reason when i add last2 it gives na object defined error.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim src As Workbook
' Abrir EXCEL
Set src = Workbooks.Open  
("U:\Mecânica\Produção\Manutenção_teste\TOA\manTOA.xlsm", True, False)
WS_Count = src.Worksheets.Count
For o = 1 To WS_Count
 src.Worksheets(o).Unprotect password:="projmanutencao"
Next o

last = src.Worksheets("Manutencao").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
folha = manutencaoexp.Label27.Caption
last2 = src.Worksheets("saidas").Range("A65536").End(x1Up).Row
    ' Escrever Registos
If manutencaoexp.ComboBox4 = "" Then
MsgBox "Introduzir todos os dados"
GoTo fim
Else
   src.Worksheets("Manutencao").Cells(last + 1, 1) = Now()                                  'data
   src.Worksheets("Manutencao").Cells(last + 1, 2) = manutencaoexp.Label28.Caption          'nº equipamento
   src.Worksheets("Manutencao").Cells(last + 1, 3) = manutencaoexp.ComboBox5                'avaria
   src.Worksheets("Manutencao").Cells(last + 1, 4) = manutencaoexp.ComboBox4                'serviços
   src.Worksheets("Manutencao").Cells(last + 1, 5) = manutencaoexp.ComboBox7                'produtos
   src.Worksheets("Manutencao").Cells(last + 1, 6) = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(folha).Cells(Monitorform.ComboBox1.ListIndex + 2, 32).Text   'duração
   src.Worksheets("Manutencao").Cells(last + 1, 7) = manutencaoexp.TextBox2                 'operario
   src.Worksheets("Manutencao").Cells(last + 1, 8) = manutencaoexp.ComboBox6                'tipo de manutenção
   src.Worksheets("Manutencao").Cells(last + 1, 9) = manutencaoexp.TextBox3                 'quantidade
   src.Worksheets("saidas").Cells(last2 + 1, 1) = manutencaoexp.ComboBox7                   'código/produtos
    'manutencaoexp.Hide
    manutencaoexp.ComboBox7 = ""
    manutencaoexp.TextBox3 = ""
    MsgBox "Dados Introduzidos com sucesso"

End If

      For o = 1 To WS_Count
 src.Worksheets(o).Protect password:="projmanutencao"
 Next o

  Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'IT WORKS TO DISABLE ALERT PROMPT

 'SAVES FILE USING THE VARIABLE BOOKNAME AS FILENAME
 src.Save

 Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'RESETS DISPLAY ALERTS

' CLOSE THE SOURCE FILE.
src.Close True             ' FALSE - DON'T SAVE THE SOURCE FILE.
Set src = Nothing

    fim:
End Sub
```

My problem is that i want to run

```
 src.Worksheets("saidas").Cells(last2 + 1, 1) = manutencaoexp.ComboBox7
```

but i get na error on

```
last2 = src.Worksheets("saidas").Range("A65536").End(x1Up).Row
```

Other than that everything is running fine.

If there's any other way around to solve this error , maybe adding another button or something else.

Comment: Why would somebody vote to close this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`last2 = src.Worksheets("saidas").Range("A65536").End(x1Up).Row`

If you look VERY carefully at this line, you'll notice that you actually have the number `1` instead of the letter `L` in `End(x1Up)`

How that happened, I have no idea. So change the line to:

`last2 = src.Worksheets("saidas").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Lol ahahah , sorry i would not repair in that small error , tired eyes . Thank you